# create a validation on zip code

Tags: validation-rule

I have created a custom field Zip Code type as text.i want to put a validation as to not allow comma or semicolon to be put in zip code field by users

How do I do that?

Comment: Validation rules would work for you!

Comment: OR(Zip_Code__c <> ',' , Zip_Code__c <> ';' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Validation rule with Regular expression like below :

"`field1__c`" is assumed to be field where you don't want comma or Semicolon

```
REGEX( field1__c , "^(\\w)*[,;]+(\\w)*$")
```

Where

`^` - Start of String

`\w` - Any word character (letter, number, underscore)

`\*` - zero or more occurrence

`\+` - one or occurrence

`$` - End of String